# Mailchimp - success message to clear the success message after the user has submitted the form in React

Tags: reactjs, react-mailchimp-subscribe

Im trying to use the Mailchimp npm package and it works as intended. However, Im trying to clear the error or success message once a user clicked 'Subscribe' as currently it doesn't go away until the page is refreshed. I dont want to refresh the page but rather display a success/error message for 5 sec and then it clears out

I tried setTimeout but it didn't really work for me. Im still learning React, any advice highly apprecaited!

Here is my code with statuses below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import MailchimpSubscribe from "react-mailchimp-subscribe"
import './Newsletter.css';
import NewsletterForm from './NewsletterForm';
import './Newsletter.css';


const Newsletter = (props) => {

  const postUrl = `https://warikerestaurant.us20.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=${process.env.REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_U}&id=${process.env.REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_ID}`;

  return (
    <div className="mc__form-container app__newsletter">
      <h3 className="mc__title app__newsletter-heading">Join our email list for future updates</h3>
      <MailchimpSubscribe
        url={postUrl}
        render={({ subscribe, status, message }) => (
          <>
            {status === "sending" && <div style={{ color: "blue" }}>please wait...</div>}
            {status === "error" && <div style={{ color: "red" }} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: message }} />}
            {status === "success" && <div style={{ color: "green" }}>You are successfully subscribed !</div>}
          <NewsletterForm
            status={status}
            message={message}
            onValidated={formData => subscribe(formData)}
          />

          </>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Newsletter;
```

I tried setTimeout with useEffect but it didn't really work, nothing was showing up. I tried to include setTimeout after

```
{status === "success" &&
```

However I dont think it works in React